# Error when putting partition column to variable

Tags: python, string, pyspark

I'm getting an error when I'm passing string variable to partitionBy. I already did put double quote to my columns but I still get the same error. Is there any way I can put dynamic columns to partitionBy?

```
partition_columns='column1,column2,column3'
final_df.write.partitionBy(partition_columns).mode("append").parquet(location)
```

I'm using pyspark

Answer (score 2):

The `partitionBy` function takes a `varargs` not a `string`.

Try using as below -

```
partition_columns=['column1','column2','column3']

final_df.write.partitionBy(*partition_columns).mode("append").parquet(location)
```

Comment: If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer. Upvote too, if you like.